# Multiple passes of table without subquery

Tags: sql, database, select, group-by, pivot

I have a table that looks like this :

```
Id   Field   Value
1    Color   Red
1    Price   10.00
1    Size    S
2    Color   Red
2    Price   10.00
2    Size    M
3    Color   Red
3    Price   20.00
3    Size    L
4    Color   Yellow
4    Price   20.00
4    Size    L
```

Step 1: I need to convert the given table into table with columns 
Id, Color, Price, Size with no duplicates and WITHOUT using sub-query for each field column.

Step 2: I need to find all pair of Id's that have atleast 2 values in common. The query must be scalable if there are more fields added so dont assume we only have Color, Price, Size.

Was asked to me in an interview but cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  You can only do Step 2 using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2):

For step 1, just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'Color' THEN value END) color,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'Price' THEN value END) price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN field = 'Size'  THEN value END) size
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
```

Step 2 does not look like something that can be done easily in regular SQL, first off because it implies to handle a variable number of columns. For this to work, as commented by Gordon Linoff, you would need to use dynamic SQL, which seems beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks @GMB  . Thats what I was thinking as well but since it was asked on a phone interview I thought there must be a way.

Comment: You just have to add "HAVING" in your SQL. Remember it says at least 2 values in common - no mention that they have to be the same field. So your one GROUP BY field is enough to cover that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

For step 2:

```
select t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2
from eav t1
join eav t2
  on  t2.Id > t1.id
  and t2.Field = t1.Field
  and t2.Value = t1.value
group by t1.id, t2.id
having count(*) >= 2
```

Result:

```
| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1   | 2   |
| 3   | 4   |
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eQx1KzqwfeUrh5KWHwvvki/0)

You can even see which values are equal with:

```
select t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2, group_concat(t1.Field) as equal_in_fields
from eav t1
join eav t2
  on  t2.Id > t1.id
  and t2.Field = t1.Field
  and t2.Value = t1.value
group by t1.id, t2.id
having count(*) >= 2
```

Result:

```
| id1 | id2 | equal_in_fields |
| --- | --- | --------------- |
| 1   | 2   | Color,Price     |
| 3   | 4   | Price,Size      |
```

Comment: you might be right. I was focusing on the result of the first step maybe I should have thought of using the original table to get the ids with common values.

Comment: I don't see any requirement not to use the original table. That would be strange.